# How do I bring multiple screen locking dialog box back to the screen in an awful and old win32 application on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows, keyboard-shortcuts, dialog, win32

When I use the win32 program in question the screen locks as it would with a shadow box on most modern applications, except without the shadow box and often with two over lapping dialogs that don't let you click on or focus on the window.

I've tried the following:

- Pressing escape (when I think the dialog is displayed)
- Pressing tab a few times and then enter (when I think the dialog is displayed)
- Holding the windows key while pressing up or down or left or right.
- Selecting the group of tasks in the task bar and clicking `move` from the context menu and then pressing the arrow keys
- Selecting the window in question in the `Task Manager`'s `Applications` tab and clicking `Switch To`
- Selecting the window in question in the `Task Manager`'s `Applications` tab and clicking `Bring to Front`
- Selecting the window in question in the `Task Manager`'s `Applications` tab and clicking `End Task` (which usually results in yet another modal dialog box!!!
- Tried changing the resolution, that did not fix the issue.

Is there anything else I can try?  The place I work uses an AWFUL AWFUL ticketing system called FrontRange that's a win32 application.

Is there anything that can be done about these modal popup dialog boxes that appear offscreen and refuse to be clicked?  Please I'm losing records of work that I've done but that I can't get credit for.

Comment: Are you talking about UAC?

Comment: @Ramhound no, that isn't involved here.  That was just an example of what modern applications do, in contrast to model dialogs that don't let you click on the window they came from (but without the added benefit of making this clear by shadow boxing the rest of the application)

Comment: You might try right-click on the Taskbar and select one of the window arrangement settings : “Cascade windows” or “Show windows stacked”.

Comment: @harrymc When it happens again I'll give it a shot.

Comment: @harrymc Nope, that didn't work either.